# “This submission failed with error code(s) 1004” when upploading app to Windows Store

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to upload my UWP app updated package (.appxupload) to the Windows Store and it tells me "This submission failed with error code(s) 1004.".
My app has only one warning with the Windows App Cert Kit, because it needs the Enterprise Authentication capability. Does anyone know what the error code 1004 means and how I can find more information what went wrong?

I read that there were some problem when using the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2 package, so I changed it to Version 6.1.12 already.

Comment: try 6.2.8 which is latest official version

Comment: I already tried with 6.2.8. That's why I change to 6.1.12.

Comment: Could you mind to make a [support ticket](http://aka.ms/storesupport) to ask the team for help?

Comment: @DasiyTian MSFT Thanks for the hint to my question in the Microsoft forum. I will create the ticket, when I am back in the office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. The package is build on a windows docker container. But there is the windows.winmd file missing in the package. That's why the error is. When building the package on the local machine, everything works.